# Is there some kind of NotNull<T> (in C++ terms) in phobos?

Tags: d, template-meta-programming

Does D's standard library contain some kind of pointer/smart pointer wrapper like  [`not_null`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i12-declare-a-pointer-that-must-not-be-null-as-not_null) from the C++ core guidelines?  Or maybe there is a well-known implementation?

Comment: FWIW not_null comes from just that: guidelines. Notwithstanding the fame/renown/reputation/community position of its authors, they're still just peeps and it's not a part of C++.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, thanks, fixed the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the standard library, no. There's a [Dub package](https://code.dlang.org/packages/notnull) for it, and it's been discussed numerous times on the forum.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such thing, perhaps because D developers decided that [Nullable(T)](https://dlang.org/library/std/typecons/nullable.html) is more useful. I am sure you can shift the *not_null logic* into Nullable(T) logic easily...